# .NET MAUI Blazor typing in searchbar updating a list and freezes UI for android app. How could I search on input without UI freeze?

Tags: c#, android, blazor, maui, hybrid-mobile-app

This problem is for Android version only. When I run the application on Windows Machine, the smooth searching on input works perfectly, but for Android it freezes.

.NET 6.0

So, there's a search input on my razor page and on every input it assigns the value to the SearchInput variable. Tried using the bind directive, but works strange because it only updates the binded variable when the element loses focus so I used oninput instead.

```
<input type="text" @oninput="@((e) => { SearchInput=e.Value.ToString();})" />
```

There's a getter for a property called productsToShow and its value depends on the SearchInput.

```
    private List<Product> productsToShow
    {
        get
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SearchInput))
            {
                return productList;
            }
            else
            {
                return productList.Where(item => item.Model.ToLower().Contains(SearchInput.ToLower())).ToList();
            }
        }
    }
```

After changing SearchInput the razor page iterates through the productsToShow list and creates a list on the UI containing ProductListItems.

```
    <div>
        @foreach (Product item in productsToShow)
        {
            <ProductListItem Product="@item" />
        }
    </div>
```

My problem is: Everytime the productsToShow changes due to the SearchInput change the UI freezes when it refreshes the list on UI with the foreach.

How could I manage to create a smooth oninput searching for Android with .NET MAUI Blazor app?

I tried many ways to make it somehow async but I think this being async is not the problem in my case, but the lack of blazor knowledge from my side.

Edit: Tried to minimalize and delete redundant code.

Edit2: Product and productList definition:

Product class:
The Image string is a Base64 very long string.

```
public class Product
{
    [JsonProperty("ui_Id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("vch_UsageType")]
    public string UsageType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("vch_EnergyType")]
    public string EnergyType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("vch_Manufacturer")]
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("vch_Model")]
    public string Model { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("vch_Image")]
    public string Image { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("list_Parameters")]
    public string Parameters { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("int_CautionPrice")]
    public int CautionPrice { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("int_DailyPrice")]
    public int DailyPrice { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("int_ListPrice")]
    public int ListPrice { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("vch_HelpLink")]
    public string HelpLink { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("bit_IsActive")]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

productList definition:
This list is loaded with Product objects from database.

```
private List<Product> productList = new List<Product>();
```

Comment: Please help create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and add it to your post.

Comment: Binding should work, but to get an event for each key press, you have to define the event type: `@bind-value="@SearchInput" @bind-value:event="oninput" />`.

Comment: @martinstoeckli Searching and list updating works fine, but my problem is the UI freezes everytime the list have to change. BUT only freezes when using the app on android. On windows, it works fine.

Comment: @gbrbabos How do you define the `Product` and `productList`, please add a Minimal, Reproducible Example to your post so we can reproduce it.

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT Sorry, I added the Product class definition and the productList declaration. productList is loaded with objects mapped from JSON from Firebase database.

Comment: @gbrbabos This could be a potential issue, consider raising a new issue:https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues on Github.